# Two PickerViews with different values

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, ios4

This is my code for two pickerviews in one view controller. However its not working for me.

```
#pragma mark UIPickerViewDelegate methods
    //PickerViewController.m
    - (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView {
        return 1;
    }

    - (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component {

        switch ([thePickerView tag]) {
            case 1: //purpose picker        
                return [m_arrPurpose count];            
            case 2:  //second picker
                return [m_arrSweep count];
            default:
                return 0;
                break;
        } 
    }

    - (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component {

        switch ([thePickerView tag]) {
            case 1: //purpose picker
            {
                //cost.text = @"Test";
                Purpose *prp = [m_arrPurpose objectAtIndex:row];
                return [prp m_purposeName];     
            }       
            case 2:  //second picker
            {
                OpenActivity *opn = [m_arrSweep objectAtIndex:row];
                return [opn m_ahhaName];
            }
            default:
                return @"";
                break;
        }
}
```

can any1 help me with this please..
thanks

Comment: Whats's the problem? what about errors, crashes, logs?

Comment: What issue u have?, what error you received on console?

Comment: To add to the existing comments, you need to tell us _what_ isn't working. Are you getting the wrong values, no values, crashes, what? As it stands this is unanswerable.

Comment: what contains inside the Purpose and openActivity class

Comment: Have you set the tags of the pickers respectively as 1 and 2?

Comment: Sorry guys for make it that ambiguous.

Comment: Sorry guys for make the question bit ambiguous. there is no crash no errors in this code however, from the thePickerView Tag, no functionality is working. I mean I'm not getting values in the picker view. but if I use single pickerview it's working and I can retrive all the values that I want.

Comment: @ShantiKamichetty thanks man. I forgot set tag at XIB. Infact I didn't know at all about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like either your tags aren't set correctly or you havent connected the datasource and delegate methods for both pickers.

Add some NSLog statements in the numberOfRowsInComponent and titleForRow: methods.

Include the picker view object and the picker view's tag in the log, e.g.

```
NSLog(@"Rows in component for %@, tag %d",thePickerView,[thePickerView tag]);
```

And a different text in the titleForRow.

You should see two different objects - if not, your delegate and datasource are not connected. You should see tags 1 and 2 - if not, your tags are not set properly.

Answer (score -1):

With this problem there was nothing wrong with my code It's just that I forgot to set tag's value to 1 and 2 in XIB.

Comment: So, the very first sentence in my answer then? Thanks for that.